# Using Python to count the number of layers in a AutoCAD file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, autocad, autocad-plugin

I've created a `GUI` using `PyQt5` wich takes `shapefiles` and one `.dwg` file as inputs.
In the `.dwg` file, I have a certain amount of standard `layers` that should be inside.
If one or more of those `layers` is missing, I would like to be able to inform the user which `layers` are missing.

For example, if the `.dwg` files must have these `layers` ('Trees', Roads', 'Houses', 'Lakes' etc.), if 'Roads' is missing, I would like the user to be inform when he launches the `GUI`.

Using Python I have to use a Python extension/library I guess. But I've looked and `PyAcad` or `PythonCAD` don't seem to be very implemented yet.
If anyone has used Python for AutoCAD, I am looking for some advice/tips.
And if you have an alternative idea for my problem that would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: I think you should parse the file. I dont know wheter .dwg is ASCII file. If it is then you can parse it.

Comment: @DigviJayPatil .dwg is binary, but .dxf is ASCII i think.

Comment: Then you can parse .dxf file

Comment: @DigviJayPatil i've opened the file in notepad++ but it's not an easy file to parse, there are so many information

Comment: Find out some keyword from file which will give you required information and then parse file with those keywords

Comment: I don't use Python, but I could do everything in C# referencing the `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop` and `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common` dlls. Can Python access regular DLL libraries? Do you mind it if Autocad opens in order to check the file? You can try using the that DLL:

The `AcadApplication` object is used to open and close Autocad and its documents.
The `AcadDocument` object contains the `Layers` collection.

Answer (score 3):

There is a complication here: if you have a .dwg you cannot convert it to .dxf without AutoCAD installed on the machine.

If you have AutoCAD installed, then use it's APIs to open and manipulate the drawing. This can be done with .NET, C++, JavaScript or any language compatible with COM (including Python).

If you DON'T have AutoCAD installed, there is a cloud API for it: AutoCAD I/O. This is basically a running instance on the cloud that you can use for processing .dwg drawings. That way you can upload a .dwg with a script to list layers. Below is the sequence of commands to list layers:

```
-layer
?
*
```

Which should return a list of layers. You can have more with .NET code running on this cloud instance. See more at http://developer.autodesk.com

Let me know what you have (scenario and goal), then I can advise better.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have AutoCAD but since the tool that I'm creating aims to be distributed to others, they may not have AutoCAD installed (though it is unlikely). Basically, what i am doing is : i have a dwg file as input and i want to know what layers are in this file (just the name of the layers). And I would like to have these names in my Python Script.